# How to make the most of a Gaussian mixture assumption in a model?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, latent-variable, gaussian-mixture-distribution

I have a dataset with 100 columns and approximately 100000 lines. 
I have a variable to predict that is Y (0,1 so it's a classification problem). 
I have an other categorical variable with two values 0 and 1.

By plotting my variables distributions, I discovered that many of my variables seem to be a mixture of two Gaussian distributions. By comparing it with the categorical value, I found that the two modes exactly fit this categorical value (meaning each distribution of individuals restricted to one of the two categories matches each Gaussian distribution of the mixture).

I feel like it is an interesting information about my variables. However I do not know how to capitalize on this. Do I have to create new variables based on the variables + the categorical one ? Do I need to use two models (1 for each value of the categorical variable) to improve the result ? What model should I use that can make the most of my observation as an hypothesis (svm , random forest, logistic reg, etc...) ?

Thanks

Comment: Gaussian distributions don't have two modes. If it has two modes it *cannot* 'seem to be Gaussian'. I have no clear idea what you do mean, though. Do you mean that you think it looks like a mixture of two Gaussians, or do you mean something else?

Comment: yes I mean it is a mixture of two gaussians. So it has two modes. Sorry if it was not clear.

Comment: Could you modify your question so it doesn't contain the expression 'Gaussian with two modes', please?